# How to debug nested web application inside @SpringBootTest

Tags: rest, debugging, intellij-idea, spring-boot-test

I am trying to run the following automated test:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MyControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    int port;

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate rest;

    private String myUrl() {
        return String.format("http://localhost:%d/...", port);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyUrl() {
        String response = rest.getForObject(myUrl(), String.class);
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

I am running it under IntelliJ Idea debugger and I can trace `testMyUrl` function. Unfortunately, any breakpoints inside controller code is ignore. This is probably because it is executed inside separate process, which debugger is not attached to.

The question is: is it possible to automate or make easy attaching to this process? I was able to do this in [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) with Quarkus plugin. Is it possible to do the same with Spring?

Comment: Hello, please see the following: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/attaching-to-local-process.html#attach-to-remote

Comment: @OlgaKlisho the problem is remote process is (probably) created internally

Comment: Can you please file a new issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. Thanks